# Include js file out of domain

Tags: javascript, include, root

I am trying to include a javascript file within a page located on the **root** of my domain, as follows:

```
<script src="../../js/typeahead.js"></script>
```

As you an see, the file is **BEYOND** the domain root. How can I include this file without absolute paths? Thanks for you time, have a nice to-day.

**Structure**:

```
/js
/sites/example/file
```

**Domain.tld** root is */sites/example/* and I am calling the js from *file*

Comment: @MarsOne Sorry, hahaha sometimes I take magic for granted... it's what happens when living in a magic world. ;)

Comment: I'd say your only hope is a server-side script that reads the contents of the JS file and outputs them between `<script>` and `</script>` tags...! Or (drum roll please....) just move the JS file?? If you tell us why that's not an option we may be able to better suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can include if it has a global access.

```
 like http://domainname/folsers/somefile.js
```

otherwise you cannot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) Just by curiosity, why isn't it possible? It seems quite logic. Thanks SHIN!

Comment: @Alberich when you include a file by `<script src="...">`, the user's web browser makes a new HTTP request to your server to fetch that JS file, separately from the original request that grabs the web page itself. (Doesn't matter that you use a relative URL, the browser just converts it to a full absolute URL and fetches it). So if that JS file isn't publicly accessible, the browser has no hope of reaching it!!

Comment: because javascript running from client side. so the client browser should have access to the js file. it cannot if its not in a global access.

Comment: Wonderful answer, thanks! Get a deserved holiday on a beach!  ;)